# Trouble with Upload Task Snapshot

Tags: angularjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a problem with displaying image on my project. I want in the **.subscribe** task the download url to equal as image. So it can display it. But when I do that it shows an error message:

> Type 'UploadTaskSnapshot' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Here is the code:

```
export class PostDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  title: string;
  image: string = null;
  content: string;

  buttonText: string = "Create Post";

  uploadPercent: Observable<number>;
  downloadURL: Observable<string>;


  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private postService: PostService, 
    private storage: AngularFireStorage
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  uploadImage(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    const path = `posts/${file.name}`
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(path);
    if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') {
      return alert('only image files')
    } else {
      const task = this.storage.upload(path, file)
      this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
      task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
         finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
      )
```

> .subscribe(url => (this.image = url))

```
      console.log('Image Uploaded!');
```

What should I change to make it work because I am an amateur. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer and is this:

```
  uploadImage(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0]
  const path = `posts/${file.name}`
  const fileRef = this.storage.ref(path);
  if (file.type.split('/')[0] !== 'image') {
  return alert('only image files')
} else {
  const task = this.storage.upload(path, file);
  const ref = this.storage.ref(path);
  this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
  console.log('Image uploaded!');
  task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      this.downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL()
      this.downloadURL.subscribe(url => (this.image = url));
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```